# Copy file via scp

Tags: linux, ssh, centos, fedora, scp

I have two servers. server `A` and `B` . I have created user on server A

script is here

```
useradd --home-dir /opt/test --no-create-home --shell /opt/test/bin/test.sh --password XXXX test
```

I want to connect server A from B via scp and copy file

```
scp -t -t  -r  /opt/test/ test@192.168.0.52:/opt/test/
```

but throws exeption

```
scp: ambiguous target
```

I have  read about this error.As I understood this is syntactic error but there is not such a problem

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK scp has no option -t (see man page http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp)

```
scp -r /opt/test/ test@192.168.0.52:/opt/test/
```

should do the job.