# SCP not working permission denied even with SSH key given

Tags: linux, scp

I am trying to get `scp` to work and transfer a file from a remote server to my local. I tried looking around and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939562/scp-permission-denied-publickey-on-ec2-only-when-using-r-flag-on-directories) post helped the most but it still is not working here is the current output.

```
<HOSTNAME>:chef4-rep
<USERNAME>$ sudo scp -i ./.chef/<NAME>.pem <USERNAME>@<IP>:/home/postgres/post_0604_dump/db0604_schema_and_data.sql ~/
<USERNAME>@<IP>: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: did you copy your public key to the remote ~./ssh/authorized_keys ?

Comment: And are the permissions on your private key and its containing directory correct?  Can you use the same key and connect manually?

Comment: @ivanivan That is what I ended up doing before I saw your comment. I posted an answer to the thread.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy file via scp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18509457/copy-file-via-scp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue turned out not to be with my command but that I was trying to copy a file in another users directory and it wouldn't work. I ended up SSH'ing in and using `sudo` to copy the file to my home directory and then used `scp` with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use below command to get it done.

root@localhost# scp -r "source_file/directory" "Destination address- remote-IP/Hostname:/location"

And if you are using passwordless ssh then make sure you are using correct user whose public keys are shared with remote server.

Thanks

Comment: I resolved the issue, I just posted it as you sent yours. It was a permissions issue that I could not access the file remotely so I had to move it, my command was correct. The -r flag is redundant because I was just transferring a single file not a directory.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with scp and got *Permission denied (publickey)*:

This worked:
`ssh -i "mykey.pem" ubuntu@??.??.??.???`

But this didn't: `scp -i "mykey.pem" test.php  ubuntu@??.??.??.???:`

I solved it by removing the quotes off my key file:

`scp -i mykey.pem test.php  ubuntu@??.??.??.???:`